# Is there any reason an ISP can't block the BridgeDB?

Tags: bridge, firewall

Keep in mind that my knowledge of Tor Bridges specifically is fairly limited (I basically only know that a bridge is an unpublished guard node that you can use to enter the Tor network without anybody realizing it at first, assuming your adversary is not using DPI. I know nothing of pluggable transports).

But take this scenario for example:
We're behind the Great Firewall of China, which blocks access to all known Tor nodes. Th obvious fix to this is to go to https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges and grab some bridge lines. This presents me with two questions:

1. Why can't the Great Firewall be modified to block access to the Tor Project's website? I understand that it uses SSL, thus cannot necessarily be directly blocked, but firewalls can be configured to spoof a DNS request and return an invalid IP address, can they not? This would block users from accessing the Bridge Database and they would not be able to access Tor without someone from outside the firewall sending them bridges in some other way.
2. What is stopping them from blocking users from downloading the Tor Browser Bundle? This is essentially a duplicate of the question above, but I'd just like to know if I'm missing any facts...

Answer (score 1):

The Tor project website and the download *can* be blocked and have been in the past and currently in some locations in the world. That is why they even offer to email you a copy or send you a secure download if you reach out to them on twitter or other means to get a copy.